# How to wait until image(s) loaded in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have some basic code to load some sprite images, I am using Future.wait to wait until both images are loaded. However this still does not what I exactly want to do, Because I want to assign image width and height to members before It exits.

```dart
SpaceShip(this.x, this.y) {
  rocket = new ImageElement(src: "nofire.png");
  firingRockets = new ImageElement(src: "fire.png");
  var futures = [rocket.onLoad.first, firingRockets.onLoad.first];
  Future.wait(futures).then((_) {
    width = rocket.width;
    height = rocket.height;
    print("Images loaded. $width $height");     
  });
  print("Returning");
}
....
ship = new SpaceShip(400.0, 200.0);
print("Ship Constructor exited");
```

The output:

```dart
Returning
Ship Constructor exited
Images loaded. 40 75
```

I want a way to wait until everything image loading done before exiting the constructor.Is there a good way to do this in Dart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added some comments why it doesn't work

```dart
SpaceShip(this.x, this.y) {
  rocket = new ImageElement(src: "nofire.png");
  firingRockets = new ImageElement(src: "fire.png");
  var futures = [rocket.onLoad.first, firingRockets.onLoad.first];
  // this call just gets enqueued in the Dart event queue and then the 
  // execution is continued at the next statement
  // the async code is executed only after this thread of execution 
  // has ended
  Future.wait(futures).then((_) {
    width = rocket.width;
    height = rocket.height;
    print("Images loaded. $width $height");     
  });
  // this code doesn't wait for Future.wait to finish
  print("Returning");
}
....
// this code doesn't wait for Future.wait to finish
ship = new SpaceShip(400.0, 200.0);
print("Ship Constructor exited");
```

This way it should work (not tested)

```dart
SpaceShip(this.x, this.y);

// I moved this to a method because the constructor can't return a Future
Future load() {
  rocket = new ImageElement(src: "nofire.png");
  firingRockets = new ImageElement(src: "fire.png");
  var futures = [rocket.onLoad.first, firingRockets.onLoad.first]; 
  return Future.wait(futures).then((_) {  // return a Future
    width = rocket.width;
    height = rocket.height;
    print("Images loaded. $width $height");     
  })
  .then(() {
    print("Returning");
  }});
}
....

var ship = new SpaceShip(400.0, 200.0);
// the returned future allows to wait until the async code has finished (using then)
ship.load().then(() {
    print("Ship Constructor exited");
});
```

Comment: I see, is there no way to force the calls to be sync?

Comment: The code is invoked by events which are async. Once a call is invoked asynchronically there is now way to go back to sync. There are plans to implement wait/await which should help here but I guess this will take some months to land.

Comment: Thanks, I kinda thought, something like waiting on a future (like Java) , but seems I should be more careful.