# In Flutter, how to load a local image as ui.image to draw it in canvas?

Tags: image, flutter, canvas, load, drawimage

I read almost all the posts but still can't find a proper way if any to load a local image as ui.image so that it can be used in `canvas.drawImage` in Flutter. I have come out with the following code block to get an `ui.image` from an Asset image. However, it took a few seconds event for a 32x32 size of image and I can't figure it out when it is fully loaded and ready to be drawn in canvas.

```
static Future<ui.Image> askImage(String path) async {
    Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
    final img = Image(image: AssetImage(path));
    img.image
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info);
    }));
    ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
    return imageInfo.image;
  }

  static ui.Image load2(String xxxx) {
    ui.Image info;
    askImage(xxxx).then((info) {
      if (info != null) {
        print(info.width);
        print(info.height);
      }
      return (info);
    });
  }
```

I'm also looking at the Image package 'https://pub.dev/packages/image' but I'm not sure how to convert `Image` from that package to `ui.image` which is needed for `canvas.drawImage` function in Flutter.  I also saw an old post here (https://flutter2015.firefirestyle.net/rendering/doc-5) but I'm not sure where does the ImageResource comes from.

Comment: I found this thread of the discussion. I need the similar function to sync preload a set of ui.Image at the start of initState. Going to give it a try.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296563/how-to-wait-until-images-loaded-in-dart